# Docker image not running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

Tags: python, docker, plotly-dash

I've created a small dash app and trying to run on docker container.I get the following message

Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

But when I try opening the link it shows trouble connecting to the page.
I tried the solution on [Docker image not running on host 8050](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67296901/docker-image-not-running-on-host-8050) but it doesn't work as well.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

ADD main.py .

RUN pip install dash

RUN pip install plotly

RUN pip install pandas

RUN pip install flask

EXPOSE 8080/tcp

CMD [ "python3" ,"./main.py" ]
```

Comment: What's the exact docker run command you executed?

Comment: You exposed **8080**, so what is 8050 supposed to do?

Comment: Get rid of the EXPOSE, it's get a lot of people confused, use -p parameter on docker run to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, you need to change the port you're exposing to 8050

```
FROM python:3.9

ADD main.py .

RUN pip install dash

RUN pip install plotly

RUN pip install pandas

RUN pip install flask

EXPOSE 8050

CMD [ "python3" ,"./main.py" ]
```

to run using docker run

```
docker run -p 8050:8050 <image_id>
```

you should then be able to access it at http://127.0.0.1:8050/

Answer (score 1):

Dockerfile like this

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /code
COPY main.py /code
RUN pip install dash plotly pandas flask
EXPOSE 8050
CMD python main.py
```

and build it
`docker build -t YOURAPP:latest .`

and run it
`docker run -p 8050:8050 YOURAPP:latest`